# Recursively count occurrences with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, recursion, recursive-query

Consider the following example table

| x_id | name_id1 | name_id2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | John | Frank |
| x2 | Frank | John |
| x3 | Jack | John |
| x4 | John | Jack |
| x5 | Bob | Frank |
| x6 | George | Bob |
| x7 | Bob | Finn |
| x8 | Mark | James |
| x9 | James | Finn |

The goal is to extract the following result

| name | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| John | 4 |
| Bob | 3 |
| James | 2 |

Conceptually this is the result of the following procedure:

1. Count the frequency of all names and pick the one that occurs most often, that would be John, which occurs 4 times (row `x1` to `x4`).
2. Now remove all rows that contain John, which leaves you with row `x5` to `x9`. Again determine the name that occurs most frequently. This gives you Bob, which occurs 3 times (row `x5` to `x7`).
3. Now *also* remove row `x5` to `x7`, which leaves us with row `x8` to `x9`. Again determine the name that occurs most frequently. This gives us James which occurs 2 times.
4. Now *also* remove row `x8` to `x9`, which leaves us with nothing, so we are done.

This data is stored in SQLite in a junction table as follows (in the real world case there can be more than two names per `x_id`)

| id | x_id | name_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x1 | John |
| 2 | x1 | Frank |
| 3 | x2 | John |
| 4 | x2 | Frank |
| 5 | x3 | John |
| 6 | x3 | Jack |
| 7 | x4 | John |
| 8 | x4 | Jack |
| 9 | x5 | Bob |
| 10 | x5 | Frank |
| 11 | x6 | Bob |
| 12 | x6 | George |
| 13 | x7 | Bob |
| 14 | x7 | Finn |
| 13 | x8 | James |
| 14 | x8 | Mark |
| 13 | x9 | James |
| 14 | x9 | Finn |

**What kind of procedure do we need to retrieve the described result?** Considering that the above junction table is of variable length (just to make sure we do not come up with a fixed amount of `join`s as a valid answer).

I did consider using the `WITH RECURSIVE` approach however that will not allow us to

1. Execute the aggregate function `COUNT` in the recursive select which seems to be required when we want to calculate the occurrences.
2. Remove all previous `x_id`s, only those that are currently in queue.

Comment: What about ties in the frequency?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're looking for?

Comment: What if there are 4 Johns and 4 Bobs? Which one should be picked first?

Comment: Good question, in that case we may pick alphabetically, in reality there is no preference between the two.

Comment: @forpas For what it’s worth: it would also be acceptable to return all items that have a tie in the frequency, if that makes the query easier/feasible.

Comment: Why does Frank not get counted? If you didn't remove his name as well as John in the first cut, he would be joint second highest.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used SQLite but recursive queries are available in many DBMSs, unfortunately I do not think they are powerful enough to do what you want. The problem is that you need to incrementally ignore more and more rows if they contain a name already present in the result table. I am not 100% sure, but I believe it is impossible to do this with a recursive CTE.

---

Considering that SQLite does not provide an extension language allowing loops (Here on SO you can find some way to replicate loops, like with recursive CTE
but I am not sure it is possible in your case), one of the possible reasonable choices is partially handling this at application-side.

1. First of all, I would create a temporary table like this one:

   ```
   CREATE TEMP TABLE visitedName (
     x_id VARCHAR(10),
     is_visited BOOLEAN
   );
   ```

   `x_id` is the same as the `x_id` column in your table (that I call `mytable`), `is_visited` is a boolean specifying whether the `x_id` must be ignored.
2. Then you fill `visitedName` with all the distinct values of `x_id`:

   ```
   INSERT into visitedName
   SELECT DISTINCT x_id, FALSE
   FROM mytable
   ```
3. Now you need to find the most popular name ignoring the rows where `is_visited` is true:

   ```
   SELECT mt.name_id, COUNT(mt.name_id) name_count
   FROM mytable mt JOIN visitedName vn ON mt.x_id = vn.x_id
   WHERE NOT vn.is_visited
   GROUP BY mt.name_id
   ORDER BY name_count DESC
   LIMIT 1
   ```

   At application-side you should retrieve the only row returned and extract the `name_id`, that is passed as parameter to the next query. If it has not returned any rows, then you are done and you can `DROP TABLE visitedName`.
4. In the end you update the `visitedName` table, marking as visited all the `x_id`s containing at least one occurence of the `name_id` got before.

   ```
   UPDATE visitedName
   SET is_visited = TRUE
   WHERE x_id IN (
     SELECT x_id
     FROM mytable
     WHERE name_id = ? -- name_id got before
   )
   ```
5. Restart from point 3.

If your connection latency is too high or the number of rows you expect in the resulting table are too many, the continuous communication between client-application and DBMS is a considerable overhead. In that case, you need something more advanced.

---

For those interested in replicating the table given by the OP, here is the script I have used:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  id integer,
  x_id varchar(10),
  name_id varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, x_id, name_id) VALUES
  (1, 'x1', 'John'),
  (2, 'x1', 'Frank'),
  (3, 'x2', 'John'),
  (4, 'x2', 'Frank'),
  (5, 'x3', 'John'),
  (6, 'x3', 'Jack'),
  (7, 'x4', 'John'),
  (8, 'x4', 'Jack'),
  (9, 'x5', 'Bob'),
  (10, 'x5', 'Frank'),
  (11, 'x6', 'Bob'),
  (12, 'x6', 'George'),
  (13, 'x7', 'Bob'),
  (14, 'x7', 'Finn'),
  (15, 'x8', 'James'),
  (16, 'x8', 'Mark'),
  (17, 'x9', 'James'),
  (18, 'x9', 'Finn');
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Indeed once such list becomes large and/or their is connection latency, it might create considerable overhead. I will leave the question unanswered until we have a fully SQLite based answer.